# How to caputre ethrent messages in real time with CAPL

Tags: ethernet, capl

I'm trying to build CAPL code to monitor Ethernet commuincation for automotive items.

I have used [on ethernetPacket *] function to capture for some/ip messages in trace.

But there were some problem when I use this function.

I think there were missing packet which I want to capture due to Baud Rate I guess
(Bause Rate: 1000Mbps)

My code like this:

```
on ethernetPacket *
{
   data_to_be_Captured = thys.byte(05);
   data_to_be_Captured2 = thys.byte(07);
   sysGetVariableString(sysvar::TAP_Var::sample,buf,elcount(buf));
   sysSetVariableString(sysvar::TAP_Var::sample,Char_arr);
   ......               
}
```

With this Ethernet function in CAPL, It was possible to capture some pacekt.

But one of them was missing when I debug it.

I guess this issue caused by speed of transimission of Etherent packet.

Is there any way to resolve this problem?

Thanks
BR

Comment: `on ethernetPacket` will be called whenever an ethernet packet is received. Could you elaborate on what "the problem" is? Apart from that, could you give some details about your use case? What do you have to do on _every_ ethernet packet received?

Comment: The problem is that some SOME/IP packet is not captured.
For example, 1111 service is captured but 1112 is not captured. 
I don't need to do on every ethernet packet. I want to capture payload of some SOME/IP packet to monitor vehicle information(e.g. car speed or car type) in real time. Is there any way to capture for specific service ID or method ID of ethernet packet?

Comment: For SOME/IP you would rather use something like `on serviceSignal`, assuming that your database is containing the signals. CANoe does the _parsing_ of the ethernet packages for you and extracts the signals, you can then use `on serviceSignal` to be triggered, whenever the signal value within a SOME/IP message has changed.